# Top-left and -right corner rounded in Javafx/CSS

Tags: css, javafx, rounded-corners

I would like to create a Pane with 2 rounded corners top-left and top-right, how can i do this in javafx?
I know that u can use "border-top-left-radius" in normal css but it wont work under javafx.
Until now I tried:

```
.calendar {
    -fx-border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
    -fx-border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Zombie

Comment: The [JavaFX CSS Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) defines the names of allowed CSS attributes.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
.calendar{

  -fx-border-radius: 10 10 0 0;
  -fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 0;

  /* top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left corners, in that order. */
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this to a `Label` using inline styling (calling the `.setStyle()` method), but it just made the Labels disappear. What am I doing wrong?