# JavaFX TextField CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

How to create JavaFX TextField look like Android TextField using JavaFX CSS ?

For example : [image: Android TextField]

I have tried lots of FX css but not achieved look like that .
Here http://jsfiddle.net/QKm37/ CSS exist for HTML input type but it is not applicable in JavaFX SceneBuilder .

For example : `/** Not Exist in JavaFX **/`

`-fx-border: none;`

`-fx-background: bottom left linear-gradient(#a9a9a9, #a9a9a9) no-repeat, bottom center linear-gradient(#a9a9a9, #a9a9a9) repeat-x, bottom right linear-gradient(#a9a9a9, #a9a9a9) no-repeat;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this in your CSS file:

```
.text-field {
    -fx-background-color: #a9a9a9 , white , white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 -1 -1 -1, 0 0 0 0, 0 -1 3 -1;
}

.text-field:focused {
    -fx-background-color: #a9a9a9 , white , white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 -1 -1 -1, 0 0 0 0, 0 -1 3 -1;
}
```

Comment: @GauravKumar Suggesting edits is a good idea, but please don't include your comment in the edit itself, but rather in the summary. I've removed it for you.

Comment: @SalutonMondo you can take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564818/top-left-and-right-corner-rounded-in-javafx-css

Answer (score 3):

There is a library for material components called jfoenix, it basically give 
javafx components a material style.
[java material library](http://jfoenix.com/index.html#start)
after adding the library just instantiate a JFXTextField()
[image: example of android styled textfield]

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer (the question was _how_ not which-lib)