# Javafx label with border radius 20

Tags: java, css, javafx, label, cornerradius

I have 3 labels as shown in the image below. I would like the first label (Hello) to have rounded edges on top left and top right, and dummy label to have rounded edges on bottom right and bottom left.

I've tried the -fx-border-radius: 30; in CSS, but it's not working. See the class I've defined in Hello label. Please help!

```
package com.binaryname.view;
public class Main extends Application {

private ConversionController conversionController = new ConversionController();

private PopupWindow keyboard;

private final Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
private final Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
private final double taskbarHeight = bounds.getHeight() - visualBounds.getHeight();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

primaryStage.setTitle("Binary Name");

Label helloLbl = new Label("Hello");
helloLbl.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
helloLbl.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", FontWeight.BOLD, 68));
helloLbl.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;padding: 20px;");
helloLbl.getStyleClass().add("hello-border-radius");
helloLbl.setTextFill(Color.web("#ffffff"));

Label myNameLbl = new Label("my name is");
myNameLbl.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
myNameLbl.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", 48));
myNameLbl.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;padding: 20px;");
myNameLbl.setTextFill(Color.web("#ffffff"));

VBox logoBox = new VBox(10);
logoBox.setId("logo");
logoBox.getChildren().addAll(helloLbl, myNameLbl);
logoBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

TextArea nameTxtArea = new TextArea();
nameTxtArea.setWrapText(Boolean.TRUE);
nameTxtArea.getStyleClass().add("center-text-area");
nameTxtArea.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", 28));
nameTxtArea.setStyle("padding: 40px;");

Label dummy = new Label(" ");
dummy.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
dummy.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", FontWeight.BOLD, 30));

Button printBtn = new Button("PRINT");
printBtn.setId("ipad-grey");
printBtn.setDisable(Boolean.TRUE);

Button convertBtn = new Button("Convert Now!");
convertBtn.setId("ipad-grey");
convertBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

@Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        nameTxtArea.setText(conversionController.getBinaryName(nameTxtArea.getText()));
    convertBtn.setDisable(Boolean.TRUE);
    printBtn.setDisable(Boolean.FALSE);
    nameTxtArea.requestFocus();
    }
});

Button resetBtn = new Button("RESET");
resetBtn.setId("ipad-grey");
resetBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    // Reset
    nameTxtArea.setText("");
    convertBtn.setDisable(Boolean.FALSE);
    printBtn.setDisable(Boolean.TRUE);
    nameTxtArea.requestFocus();
    }
});

HBox hBox = new HBox(100);
hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
hBox.getChildren().addAll(convertBtn, printBtn);

VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
vBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
vBox.getChildren().addAll(logoBox, nameTxtArea, dummy, hBox, resetBtn);
vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;margin: 20px;");

printBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    // Start printing
    print(vBox, nameTxtArea.getText());
    convertBtn.setDisable(Boolean.FALSE);
    printBtn.setDisable(Boolean.TRUE);
    nameTxtArea.setText("");
    nameTxtArea.requestFocus();
    }
});

Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm() );

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setX(visualBounds.getMinX());
primaryStage.setY(visualBounds.getMinY());
primaryStage.setWidth(visualBounds.getWidth());
primaryStage.setHeight(visualBounds.getHeight());

adjustTextAreaLayout(nameTxtArea);

primaryStage.show();

// attach keyboard to first node on scene:
Node first = scene.getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
if (first != null) {
    FXVK.init(first);
    FXVK.attach(first);
    keyboard = getPopupWindow();
}

// Attach the on focus listener
nameTxtArea.focusedProperty().addListener((ob, b, b1) -> {
    if (keyboard == null) {
        keyboard = getPopupWindow();
    }

    keyboard.setHideOnEscape(Boolean.FALSE);
    keyboard.setAutoHide(Boolean.FALSE);
    keyboard.centerOnScreen();
    keyboard.requestFocus();

    Double y = bounds.getHeight() - taskbarHeight - keyboard.getY();
    nameTxtArea.setMaxHeight((bounds.getHeight() * 0.4));
    nameTxtArea.setMinHeight((bounds.getHeight() * 0.4));
    nameTxtArea.setPrefHeight((bounds.getHeight() * 0.4));

    /*
    * keyboard.yProperty().addListener(obs -> {
    * 
    * Platform.runLater(() -> { }); });
    */

});

}

/**
* The main() method is use to launch the Javafx gui.
* 
* @param args
*            not used
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

/**
* The print() method is use to print the text with given dimension
* 
* @param node1
*            to be printed
* @param text
*            to be written
*/
private void print(Node node1, String text) {
    // Create a printer job for the default printer

    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
    Paper label = PrintHelper.createPaper("4x2",  Constants.PRINT_RECEIPT_VERTICAL, Constants.PRINT_RECEIPT_HOZRIZONTAL, Units.INCH);
    PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(label,    PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.EQUAL);

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    Node node = createFullNode(text);

    double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() /     node1.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
    double scaleY = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight() / node1.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
    node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scaleX, scaleY));

    if (job != null) {
        // Print the node
        boolean printed = job.printPage(node);

        if (printed) {
            // End the printer job
            job.endJob();
        } else {
            // Write Error Message
            System.out.println("Printing failed.");
        }
    } else {
        // Write Error Message
        System.out.println("Could not create a printer job.");
    }

    node.getTransforms().remove(node.getTransforms().size() - 1);
}

/**
 * The getPopupWindow() method is use to show keyboard on demand
 * 
 * @return the keyboard instance
 */
private PopupWindow getPopupWindow() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    final Iterator<Window> windows = Window.impl_getWindows();

    while (windows.hasNext()) {
        final Window window = windows.next();
        if (window instanceof PopupWindow) {
            if (window.getScene() != null && window.getScene().getRoot() != null) {
                Parent root = window.getScene().getRoot();
                if (root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().size() > 0) {
                    Node popup = root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
                    if (popup.lookup(".fxvk") != null) {
                        FXVK vk = (FXVK) popup.lookup(".fxvk");
                        // hide the keyboard-hide key
                        vk.lookup(".hide").setVisible(false);
                        return (PopupWindow) window;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * The createFullNode() method is use to create an imaginary node that will
 * be used for printing
 * 
 * @param text
 *            that will be printed
 * @return the node to be printed
 */
private Node createFullNode(String text) {

    Label helloLbl = new Label("Hello");
    helloLbl.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    helloLbl.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", FontWeight.BOLD, 68));
    helloLbl.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;padding: 20px;");
    helloLbl.setTextFill(Color.web("#ffffff"));

    Label myNameLbl = new Label("my name is");
    myNameLbl.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    myNameLbl.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", 48));
    myNameLbl.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;padding: 20px;");
    myNameLbl.setTextFill(Color.web("#ffffff"));

    VBox logoBox = new VBox(10);
    logoBox.setId("logo");
    logoBox.getChildren().addAll(helloLbl, myNameLbl);
    logoBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    TextArea nameTxtArea = new TextArea();
    nameTxtArea.setWrapText(Boolean.TRUE);
    nameTxtArea.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", 28));
    nameTxtArea.setStyle("padding: 20px;");
    nameTxtArea.setText("\n\n\n\n" + text);
    nameTxtArea.getStyleClass().add("center-text-area");

    Label dummy = new Label(" ");
    dummy.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
    dummy.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", FontWeight.BOLD, 50));

    VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(logoBox, nameTxtArea, dummy);
    vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;margin: 20px;");

     vBox.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());

    return vBox;
}

/**
 * The adjustTextAreaLayout() method is use to adjust the textarea layout.
 * It will attach the listener when text is changed
 * 
 * @param textArea
 */
private void adjustTextAreaLayout(TextArea textArea) {
    textArea.applyCss();
    textArea.layout();

    ScrollPane textAreaScroller = (ScrollPane) textArea.lookup(".scroll-pane");
    Text text = (Text) textArea.lookup(".text");

    ChangeListener<? super Bounds> listener = (obs, oldBounds, newBounds) -> centerTextIfNecessary(textAreaScroller, text);
    textAreaScroller.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(listener);
    text.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(listener);

}

/**
 * The centerTextIfNecessary() method is called when each text written. This
 * method then calculate the vertical alignment
 * 
 * @param textAreaScroller
 * @param text
 */
private void centerTextIfNecessary(ScrollPane textAreaScroller, Text text) {
    double textHeight = text.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
    double viewportHeight = textAreaScroller.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
    double offset = Math.max(0, (viewportHeight - textHeight) / 2);
    text.setTranslateY(offset);
    Parent content = (Parent) textAreaScroller.getContent();
    for (Node n : content.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
        if (n instanceof Path) { // caret
            n.setTranslateY(offset);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my interface

[image: this is my interface]

This is the entire CSS in style.css
Everything works fine except for border-radius.

```
.center-text-area *.text {
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}

.helloLbl{
    -fx-border-radius: 20 20 0 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 20 20 0 0; 
}

#hello-radius{
    -fx-border-radius: 20 20 0 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 20 20 0 0;
}

#ipad-grey {
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(#686868 0%, #232723 25%, #373837 75%, #757575 100%),
        linear-gradient(#020b02, #3a3a3a),
        linear-gradient(#b9b9b9 0%, #c2c2c2 20%, #afafaf 80%, #c8c8c8 100%),
        linear-gradient(#f5f5f5 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #cacaca 51%, #d7d7d7 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,4,5;
    -fx-background-radius: 9,8,5,4;
    -fx-padding: 15 30 15 30;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
    -fx-font-size: 30px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: #333333;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(255,255,255,0.2) , 1, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
    margin: 100px;
    -fx-pref-width: 300px;
}

#ipad-grey Text {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , white , 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}

#logo {
    -fx-background-image: url("cmh_logo_trans.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    -fx-background-size: 270 190;
    -fx-background-position: top left;
}
```

This is the fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Why did you use controller for styling? .css file is supposed to do that all....that makes code seperated from designing stuff :p

Answer (score 2):

I got a border radius by setting a new background and giving it a cornerRadius value. Like so..

```
    Label lbl = new Label();
    Color col = Color.rgb(205,205,205);
    CornerRadii corn = new CornerRadii(10);
    Background background = new Background(new BackgroundFill(col, corn, Insets.EMPTY));
    lbl.setBackground(background);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can round whichever edge you want like this

```
.helloLbl{//hello label id
        -fx-border-radius: 20 20 0 0; 
        -fx-background-radius: 20 20 0 0; 
/* top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left corners, in that order. */
 }
```

Comment: I tried that, I even tried doing that with VBox logoBox, but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: I added helloLbl.setId("hello-radius"); then called that on CSS  as #hello-radius then your code above, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Can you provide me more information, and specifics on how it should look like both in java and css?

Comment: @Rman031 if you are using .css ..then you have to attach it to .fxml file...easy way is using scene builder. Did you do it?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I've added the fxml to the same package as my main.java and css. I also opened the scene builder, added BorderPane and added the CSS file path to Stylesheets in properties. What do I do from here? GUI is already created as shown in the screenshot above. I'm not sure if BoderPane was the right one to select.

Comment: @Rman031 no worries. It should work now if your fxml is attached to controller.does other functions work?

Comment: @Rman031 did you create your gui over borderpane from start?may be this can help you.http://stackoverflow.com/q/16564818/6789999

Comment: Btw you kept background label of hello as red and also hello is already on red area..how will you notice the difference ? Change it..then use shadow or other effects to see the changes

Comment: It's not BorderPane. Let me show you the entire code to give you a larger picture.

Comment: okay minigeek, now you can see the entire code. Node is called for print (through printer) everything from Hello Label to Dummy Label . That's why it repeats the interface code.

Comment: change `vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;margin: 20px;");` to `vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;margin: 20px;");`because of it you weren't able to notice difference . Now remove .hellloLbL part from css because you kept different id in css (hello-radius). Unfornutaely I can't run your codes bcoz i don't have those libs. Vbox with red bg, Label with red bg, even if it get circled around corners you can't notice, can you? ;)

Comment: your fxml file is blank, why? :/